# System.BadImageFormatException while connecting to DB2 from .Net

Tags: c#, .net, db2, connection

I have DB2 server that I'm trying to connect from my machine, but I keep getting the below error when I start the application, before even start the connection

> System.BadImageFormatException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'IBM.Data.DB2, Version=9.7.4.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7c307b91aa13d208' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.'

please not that I don't have DB2 driver installed on my machine. but I refer to the below libraries in my application, which I got them from DB2 database server.

- IBM.Data.DB2;
- IBM.Data.DB2.Entity;
- IBM.Data.Informix;

Comment: looks like you are missing some assemblies required for using your db2 provider client lib. you might wanna search what is missing and install the proper packages or runtimes.

Comment: How can I know what's the missing assemblies ?

Comment: By getting to know what are your runtime assemblies. a simple google search can help with that.

Comment: Those libraries need need a driver.  You need to go into Admin tools and add an ODBC connection to the DB2 server.

Comment: I don't have DB2 option in ODBC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally the error message is caused by a 32/64 bit conflict.

Your program could be compiled in 64 bit (or any) and the drivers in 32 bit or the other way round.

Check the Configuration Manager and set the Platform to x86 or x64.